# StandAlone CDI + JTA Without JNDI

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, cdi

I am using CDI + DeltaSpike + Camel in a standalone app.

Here is my current setup :

persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <shared-cache-mode>DISABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
</persistence-unit>
```

Custom properties on EntityManagerFactoryProducer:

```
properties.put("hibernate.connection.provider_class", "org.example.HikariConnectionProvider");
```

I'm using DeltaSpike JPA Transaction with (https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/jpa.html):

- org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.api.transaction.TransactionScoped;
- org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.api.transaction.Transactional;

---

I would like to use Infinispan to sync my app caches.
According to Infinispan doc:

"It is highly recommended that Hibernate is configured with JTA transactions"

How can I use JTA transactions ?
I tried to change "RESOURCE_LOCAL" to "JTA" but I don't understand what am I supposed to configure for :

- hibernate.transaction.factory_class
- hibernate.transaction.jta.platform

I am not using JNDI, and I am not in an application server.

Also, I would like to use @javax.transaction.Transactional instead of DeltaSpike.

Answer (score -1):

Essentially, you are asking how to use most Java EE features without using a Java EE container.

Of course, there are JTA implementations like Atomikos you can embed in a "standalone" application.

On the other hand, it might be a lot easier to start with a full-blown Java EE environment and then ignore or exclude anything you don't need.

App servers are rather lightweight these days, and if a self-contained executable is a must-have for you, then have a look at WildFly Swarm or Payara Micro.